# Assign IEnumerable list inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having an issue with following linq query.

```
public class Address
    {
        public int addressID { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

public class AdvanceClient
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; } 

    }
```

In the below linq query i want to assign IEnumerable list of addresses to the Addresses property. I'm having a one to many relationship between tblAdvanceClient and tblAddress tables.

```
IEnumerable<AdvanceClient> addcli = from tbcli in dc.tblAdvanceClients
                                                join tbadd in dc.tblAddresses
                                                on tbcli.AddressID equals tbadd.AddressID
                                                select new AdvanceClient
                                                {
                                                    ClientID = tbcli.ClientID,
                                                    Company = tbcli.Company,
                                                    Fax = tbcli.Fax,
                                                    Mobile = tbcli.Mobile,
                                                    Name = tbcli.Mobile,
                                                    Telephone = tbcli.Telephone,
                                                    Addresses = new Address { } // Here i need to get the list of address to each client
                                                };
```

[image]

Comment: how can one client has more than one address if addresses and clients tables have one-to-one relationship (Client.ClinetID - Client.AddressID -> Address.AddressID)?

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
Address = new Address { }
```

Change it to

```
Address = tbcli.Addresses //Since you already have a property in AdvanceClient
```

So your query would be:

```
IEnumerable<AdvanceClient> addcli = 
        from tbcli in dc.tblAdvanceClients
        join tbadd in dc.tblAddresses
            on tbcli.AddressID equals tbadd.AddressID
            select new AdvanceClient
            {
                ClientID = tbcli.ClientID,
                Company = tbcli.Company,
                Fax = tbcli.Fax,
                Mobile = tbcli.Mobile,
                Name = tbcli.Mobile,
                Telephone = tbcli.Telephone,
                Address = tbcli.Addresses
            };
```

Comment: Hello! Actually the Address column in tblAdvanceclient is a different one and it does not related to the address list i'm talking about

Comment: @chamara, closely looking at your table design, you will have a single address against a client, agasint a single entry in Address, you will have multiple clients, is that the requirement ? because it seems wrong, it should be otherway, like a client can/could have multiple addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using EntityFramework to retrieve the data? If so, then you can alter your model

```
 

public class Address
    {
        public int addressID { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

public class AdvanceClient
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }

        public virtual Address Addresses { get; set; } 

    }
```

EntityFramework will load the address data for you.

Answer (score 1):

This design is a bit strange to me, having an address list that always contains only one item, but if you definitely need this you can query with the following:

```
    var addcli = from tbcli in dc.tblAdvanceClients
                join tbadd in dc.tblAddresses
                on tbcli.AddressID equals tbadd.AddressID into addrList
                select new AdvanceClient
                {
                    ClientID = tbcli.ClientID,
                    Company = tbcli.Company,
                    Fax = tbcli.Fax,
                    Mobile = tbcli.Mobile,
                    Name = tbcli.Mobile,
                    Telephone = tbcli.Telephone,
                    Addresses = from row in addrList
                                select new Address 
                                {
                                    addressID = row.AddressID, 
                                    address = row.Address 
                                }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I didn't understand right but I think it should be as below since addresses and clients tables has one-to-one reletionship through AddressID

```
public class Address
{
    public int addressID { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class AdvanceClient
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    //It can has only one address
    public Address Address { get; set; } 

}
```

And query:

```
IEnumerable<AdvanceClient> addcli = from tbcli in dc.tblAdvanceClients
                                    join tbadd in dc.tblAddresses
                                    on tbcli.AddressID equals tbadd.AddressID
                                    select new AdvanceClient
                                    {
                                        ClientID = tbcli.ClientID,
                                        Company = tbcli.Company,
                                        Fax = tbcli.Fax,
                                        Mobile = tbcli.Mobile,
                                        Name = tbcli.Mobile,
                                        Telephone = tbcli.Telephone,
                                        //tbadd is the address which you are looking for
                                        Addresses = tbadd;
                                    };
```